# simple way to make 3.2242143 to 3.2 using jquery 

Tags: javascript, jquery, floating-point

i have many data like this :

```
3.23214215
```

but i want to use the `3.2` part ,

what can i do  using jquery ,

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
yourNumber.toFixed(1);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed

Answer (score 3):

You can use plain Javascript:

```
var n = 3.23214215
var fixed = n.toFixed(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery, plain old javascript does the trick:

```
var chopped = Math.floor(full_length * 10.0) / 10.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in plain old Javascript:

```
var f = 3.23214215;
f *= 10;
var i = parseInt(f);
f = i / 10;
```

You could also look into the Math object. There might be a rounding function in it.

Comment: Nah, schneck and Vadiklk have better solutions.